# How to compare two array object in javascript if it match want to update object in array1?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have two array objects and want to compare them in such a way that when the `symbol` value in `array1` matches the `keyNumber` in `array2` then set the corresponding `checked` value in `array1` to `true`.

I am using `.map` with both arrays but not able to get the desired result.

These are my two arrays:-

```
const array1 = [{
    symbol: '1',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    symbol: '2',
    alias: 'abc',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    symbol: '3',
    alias: 'def',
    checked: false
  }];

const array2= [{
  keyNumber: '1',
   type: 'number',
 },
 {
   keyNumber: '2',
   type: 'number'
  }];
```

Following is the code to get updated array:

```
 const array3 = array1.map(item => {
      return array2
        .map(key =>
          key.keyNumber === item.symbol
            ? { ...item, checked: true, type: key.type }
            : item
        )
        .reduce((obj, data) => data, {});
    });

console.log(array3);
```

I am getting only last key matched result instead of all.

```
 array3 = [{
    symbol: '1',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    symbol: '2',
    alias: 'abc',
    checked: true,
    type: 'number'
  },
  {
    symbol: '3',
    alias: 'def',
    checked: false
  }];
```

Expected output:

```
array3 = [{
    symbol: '1',
    checked: true,
    type:'number'
  },
  {
    symbol: '2',
    alias: 'abc',
    checked: true,
    type: 'number'
  },
  {
    symbol: '3',
    alias: 'def',
    checked: false
  }];
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you can check my solution.

```
const newArray = array1.map(obj1 => {
  const match = array2.find(obj2 => obj1.symbol === obj2.keyNumber);
  if(match) {
    obj1 = {...obj1, checked: true, type: match.type}
  }
  return obj1;

})
```

Here is the full working code.

```js
const array1 = [{
    symbol: '1',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    symbol: '2',
    alias: 'abc',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    symbol: '3',
    alias: 'def',
    checked: false
  }];

const array2= [{
  keyNumber: '1',
   type: 'number',
 },
 {
   keyNumber: '2',
   type: 'number'
  }];

const newArray = array1.map(obj1 => {
  const match = array2.find(obj2 => obj1.symbol === obj2.keyNumber);
  if(match) {
    obj1 = {...obj1, checked: true, type: match.type}
  }
  return obj1;
    
})


console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with `reduce` by concatenating the second array in the last. In this case you wont have to find the first array for every loop.

```js
var array1 = [{ symbol: '1', checked: false }, { symbol: '2', alias: 'abc', checked: false }, { symbol: '3', alias: 'def', checked: false }]; 
var array2= [{ keyNumber: '1', type: 'number', }, { keyNumber: '2', type: 'number' }];

array1 = [...array1, ...array2];

var result = Object.values(array1.reduce((acc, {symbol, keyNumber, ...rest})=>{
  data1 = symbol || keyNumber;
  acc[data1] = acc[data1] || {};
  if(symbol) acc[data1] = {symbol, ...rest};
  if(keyNumber) { acc[data1].type = rest.type, acc[data1].checked=true };
  return acc;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```